# mysql db structure and relationship

Tags: php, mysql, relationship

I need help in how to setup my tables in my mysql database.

I have an user.  An user gets 10 tokens to use as they wish.  A token can be used only for one thing only.  They can use it to create a cartoon page, game page, bio page, question page, and etc.  The token can be reassigned to another page also.

I want to see what the best way to structure my database would be and the relationships.

I am thinking of having a user table, token table, cartoon table, game table, bio table, and question table.  But how do I relate to all of them.

Comment: this can be easily done in a very effective manner by [Relational database management system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system)

Comment: When you say relate to all of them.. what kind of relating are u looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

Relational database table design is not a hard science. It's a highly flexible paradigm that can and will change depending on the nature of your application. That being said, there are certain design principles which you should typically adhere to. See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_design.

That being said, I'll take a shot at this from an approach that seems highly dynamic, since I'm not sure about  the application specifics. Firstly, you will most definitely need a `users` table that might look like:

users:

- first_name
- last_name
- user_id
- n_tokens

  - I put this here in case a user's number of tokens is dynamic

Now that you have a way of specifying a user, you'll want to see how that user has used his/her tokens:

tokens:

- token_id

  - This is used to specify what this (or these) token(s) are used for.
- user_id

  - This should have a duplicate foreign key constraint on users.user_id.
- n_tokens

  - This is different from users.n_tokens. It is not clear from your problem
    whether or not you'll always have 1 token per feature. This value is a
    forward-looking approach at possible future enhancements.
- pagetype_id

  - This is to specify what type of page type the token is used for. It'll have
    a foreign key constraint on pagetypes.pagetype_id (see below).

As noted above, you want people to use tokens on specific page types, like cartoon pages, bio pages, etc. which this table defines:

pagetypes:

- pagetype_id

  - Used to define a unique identifier to this type of page
- pagetype_name

  - String field to label the page types, e.g. "cartoon," "bio," etc.

Now, you may have several tables defining the types of pages, so I'll specify the layout for just one:

bio_pages:

- pagetype_id

  - This id has a duplicate foreign key constraint on pagetypes.pagetype_id.
    The value will ALWAYS be constant for this table. This is not the most
    normalized design, as you MAY want to have a more generic 'pages' table,
    but several complex joins can be confusing to some developers and even
    worse, slow for queries.
- token_id

  - Foreign key constraint on tokens.token_id.
- OTHER

  - The rest of the fields are user-defined, as you wish to specify what
    belongs on a bio page.

SUMMARY

To summarize the above table layouts, you'll want to design the database so that self-contained entities do not span multiple tables, and multiple entities don't combine into one table. With that said, I separated out the `users` table from the `tokens` table from the different `<pagetype>_pages` tables. To make the design more intuitive I'll make some sample queries that might help with your understanding of the layout.

1. To get all the bio pages that a user has created:

   ```
   SELECT    bio_pages.*
   FROM      bio_pages
   INNER
   JOIN      tokens
       ON    bio_pages.token_id=tokens.token_id
   INNER
   JOIN      users
       ON    tokens.user_id=users.user_id
   WHERE     users.first_name='john'
       AND   users.last_name='doe'
   ```
2. To get the total number of coins that a user has used, and also the maximum number of coins they can use:

   ```
   SELECT    SUM(tokens.n_tokens) AS used_tokens,
             users.n_tokens       AS max_tokens
   FROM      tokens
   INNER
   JOIN      users
       ON    tokens.user_id=users.user_id
   WHERE     users.first_name='john'
       AND   users.last_name='doe'
   GROUP BY  users.user_id
   ```

Hopefully this all makes sense and is intuitive. Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: thank you very much...i will try to implement this structure...and let you know how it goes.